# Backup a remote server with Clonezilla

Tags: server, backup, clonezilla

I've got a Virtual Private Server and I would rather make a backup. The fact is I got the cheapest VPS and it comes without any backup feature.

So I wondered if it were possible to use CloneZilla to make a disk image of my server.

Comment: Clonezilla requires the partition/drives to be cloned be unmounted first. If you are just running websites in this server you do not need an image, you can back up only the data (using `tar` if no other options are available, I guess)

Answer (score 2):

It depends: if you have console access (that is: can you access the BIOS and boot the server remotely from different partitions) then yes, you can use CloneZilla by installing it on a small FAT partition of your disk and booting it from there once the install is finished.

If you only have access to Ubuntu itself after it was booted, then no, CloneZilla is not the tool for you.

If you would like a software recommendation on which tool to use, go to [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), a sister site to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: I have sudo access to Ubuntu. I can launch `shutdown -r now` command line but I don't know if it is enough

Comment: No, I'm talking IP access to a KVM switch...  I have a thought doing it without, but I need a `parted --list` output of your system. (very remote possibility)  And you need more rep too: so go around hunting for other people's questions and get some answers out there too: 20 rep is the minimum for me to be able to help you...